# Чи можна оформляти пряму мову таким чином?

Tags: пунктуація, пряма-мова

Чи буде правильним, якщо в художньому творі (напр. в детективі) я оформлю пряму мову таким чином:

**Іван:** Привіт.

**Петро:** Привіт, - голос в нього був веселий.

**Іван:** Як справи? - він поліз у кишеню. - Чуєш? Кажу, як справи?

**Петро:** Добре.

Така пунктуація більш поширена в сценаріях, але чи можна використовувати її в книгах?

**Тобто:**

- Чи можна використовувати фрази: "Іван", "Петро" на початку рядка?
- Чи можна виділяти їх жирним шрифтом?
- Чи можна після репліки додавати якісь вирази, як-от: "він поліз у кишеню"?

Comment: Будь ласка, уточніть запитання. «Таким чином» — може мати багато інтерпретацій. Про що са́ме ви запитуєте? Про жирний шрифт? Про параграфовий відступ між репліками? Про одиничний (замість подвійного) character spacing при позначенні імені персонажа? Про дефіс (замість m-dash) при виділенні прямої мови? Про ще щось?

Comment: Здебільшого саме так оформлюють п'єси, де актори читають тексти по ролях.